# Substituting multiple occurrences of a character inside a grep match

Tags: regex, grep, textwrangler

I am trying to use TextWrangler to take a bunch of text files, match everything within some angle-bracket tags (so far so good), and for *every* match, substitute all occurrences of a specific character with another.

For instance, I'd like to take something like

```
xx+xx <f>bar+bar+fo+bar+fe</f> yy+y <f>fee+bar</f> zz
```

match everything within `<f>` and `</f>` and then substitute all +'s with, say, *'s (but ONLY inside the "f" tag).

```
xx+xx <f>bar*bar*fo*bar*fe</f> yy+y <f>fee*bar</f> zz
```

I think I can easily match "f" tags containing +'s with an expression like

```
<f>[^<]*\+[^<]*</f>
```

but I have no idea on how to substitute only a subclass of character for each match. I don't know a priori how many +'s there are in each tag.
I think I should run a regular expression for all matches of the first regular expression, but I am not really sure how to do that.

(In other words, I would like to match all +'s but only inside specific angle-bracket tags).

Does anyone have a hint?

Thanks a lot,
Daniele

Comment: Is this question **really** about the UNIX tool `grep` as tagged or is it about some function of the same name within some tool named `TextWrangler` which hasn't been tagged?

Comment: Hi, honestly that can be both. If I can do it in TextWrangler (which I forgot to tag - I'll fix straight away, sorry), via its grep function, that would be perfect. If there's another way with command line "grep" (I'm on OSX) that might also work...

Comment: UNIX grep isn't for doing substitutions it's for doing `g/re/p` (there is a clue in it's name :-) ), i.e. it's to Globally find a RegExp and Print the matching string. It'd be trivial with awk if you're open to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're OK with an awk solution:

```
$ awk '{
    while ( match($0,/<f>[^<]*\+[^<]*<\/f>/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/\+/,"*",tgt)
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}' file
xx+xx <f>bar*bar*fo*bar*fe</f> yy+y <f>fee*bar</f> zz
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box. It relies on there being no `<` within each `<f>...</f>` as indicated by your sample code. If there can be then include that in your example and we can tweak the script to handle it:

```
$ awk '{
    gsub("</f>",RS)
    while ( match($0,/<f>[^\n]*\+[^\n]*\n/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/\+/,"*",tgt)
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    gsub(RS,"</f>")
    print
}' file
xx+xx <f>bar*bar*fo*bar*fe</f> yy+y <f>fee*bar</f> zz
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. Is there a way to tweak it should I need to substitute TWO characters? E.g. + with * and, say - with _. (I need to look much more into it before being able to understand what it does...)

Comment: And yes – now that you mention it, I could indeed have other tags within the <f> tag, say <f>xx+yy+<g>zz</g>+ww</f>. I guess your second example should solve the issue (it is unclear to me what the RS does exactly: is it equivalent to \n?). Thanks so much again.

Comment: for your first question - sure, it's only software and so anything is possible. Just add a line that says `gsub(/-/,"_",tgt)` under the existing gsub() line. For your second - awk reads records that are separated by whatever value `RS` contains. It's almost always `\n` but sometimes `\r\n` and sometimes other things. In your case I'm assuming that RS is `\n`. So I'm replacing `</f>` with a char that cannot currently appear in  the record (since records are **separated** by RS) so I can then negate that char in the regexp `[^\n]*`. That will work whether `RS` is `\n` alone or `\r\n`.

Comment: Thank you, everything is much clearer now. Just one last question: what if between my tags I also allowed having new lines \n? Could I set RS differently to avoid confusion?

Comment: You can hack it by throwing in control-chars and hope they don't show up in your data but it's not that easy to handle that robustly for **any** input since then you'd need to figure out what string DOES separate your records, and depending on  your awk version you may or may not be able to use a multi-char string for RS, and there are various possible solutions. It's not a huge deal but we'd just have to see what your data really looks like.